# How can I wrap a string separated by comma in Regex.Replace method and in quotes?

Tags: regex

I need some help with some regex to wrap a long list of words in quotes and inside a C# `Regex.Replace` method...my regex skills are almost non-existent. The list is similiar to the following example:

```
item one, item two
item three, item four with some addition words
item five, item six
```

Which I want to rewrite as:

```
Regex.Replace(inputstring, @"\bitem one\b", "item two")
Regex.Replace(inputstring, @"\bitem three\b", "item four with some addition words")
Regex.Replace(inputstring, @"\bitem five\b", "item six")
```

I just need a regex expression to convert these using a texteditor (Sublime Text, Notepad++, etc).

I've tried using this regex expression: `(\w+)`, but this wraps quotes around each individual word - if the replacement string has multiple words, this definitely doesn't work.

Comment: **Note:** The tag on this question is misleading, the asker wants to write C# code using a text editor and regular expressions, he/she is not referring to using the `Regex` class within C# necessarily (except as part of the text output).

Comment: @SpikeX Or, is it what you think the question really is :)

Comment: Well, @L.B, considering the asker states "*I just need a regex expression to convert these using a texteditor*", I'm pretty sure that's what is meant here.

Comment: @SpikeX, thanks for suggestion. I will remove the C# tag from the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
^([^,\n]+),\s*(.+)
```

This will store the part before the comma into `$1` and the part after it in `$2`. Then replace with:

```
Regex.Replace(inputstring, @"\b$1\b", "$2")
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/wX3fH5)

Answer (score 1):

Break it into three operations:

1. Replace `^` (or `^.`) with `Regex.Replace(inputstring, @"\b`.
2. Replace all `,` with `\b", "`.
3. Replace `$` (or `.$`) with `");`.

I perform operations like this all the time. There's no need to over-complicate it. [K.I.S.S.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)